# Creating Constants For Use In Annotation Fields

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm incorporating cache in an existing spring project using `Spring` annotations. I have created this class for storing cache configuration -

```
public class CacheParams {

    public final String name;    
    public final int lifeTime;    
    public final TimeUnit lifeTimeUnit;    
    public final String key;

    public CacheParams(args here) {/*implementation here*/}
}
```

and this is how I intend to use it -

```
class FooDaoCache extends FooDaoImpl {

    private static final CacheParam USER_BY_ID_CACHE = new CacheParams(values here);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = USER_BY_ID_CACHE.name, key = USER_BY_ID_CACHE.key)
    public User getUser(int userId) {
        implementation here
    }
}
```

But this does not work as `USER_BY_ID_CACHE` will be created on compile time. If I simply create a string constant containing cache name I can successfully use it -

```
class FooDaoCache extends FooDaoImpl {
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "baz";

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_NAME)
    public User getUser(int userId) {
        //implementation here
    }
}
```

Is there any way to deal with this or an alternate design? I need the class `CacheParams` because I have to perform other operations using cache name, lifetime etc in other parts of code too.

Comment: No, you pretty much have to use a `static final String` in order to use it in an annotation.  If this is the same string you'd pass to the `CacheParams` constructor, then use the string constant as the constructor parameter.

Comment: You are setting a constant value as 'key' ! Then how you indent to store multiple `User` in cache? At least remove the key attribute in `@Cacheble` then try in your way and post your result. For Spring cache **remember to create a bean**, `CacheManager` with the cache `USER_BY_ID_CACHE.name` in your Spring container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CacheParam` needs to be an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) or the `name` field needs to be a `static final String`.

Annotation return types may only be primitive types, enums, Strings, classes and arrays of these.